# how to get latest file in each dir

Tags: shell, files, ls, sort

Is there a Unix command to get the latest file in logsarchive of each
dir of `/app/instance`? In the example below, I have 5 folders in
`/app/instance`: `as_a`, `as_b`, `as_c`, `aunz`, `naeu` and I need to
get the latest `weekend.log` file in each archive folder.

File:

```
18790 Nov 15 13:48 /app/instance/as_a/logsarchive/log_20151115_134850/weekend.log
24533 Nov 15 14:20 /app/instance/aunz/logsarchive/log_20151115_141952/weekend.log
69906 Nov 21 08:30 /app/instance/naeu/logsarchive/log_20151121_083000/weekend.log
37923 Nov 21 11:10 /app/instance/as_a/logsarchive/log_20151121_111000/weekend.log
30830 Nov 21 11:15 /app/instance/as_b/logsarchive/log_20151121_111500/weekend.log
16186 Nov 21 11:20 /app/instance/as_c/logsarchive/log_20151121_112000/weekend.log
36365 Nov 21 11:25 /app/instance/as_c/logsarchive/log_20151121_112500/weekend.log
28407 Nov 22 01:23 /app/instance/as_b/logsarchive/log_20151122_012247/weekend.log
28407 Nov 22 10:14 /app/instance/aunz/logsarchive/log_20151122_101339/weekend.log
50945 Nov 28 08:30 /app/instance/naeu/logsarchive/log_20151128_083000/weekend.log
32704 Nov 28 11:10 /app/instance/as_a/logsarchive/log_20151128_111000/weekend.log
30931 Nov 28 11:15 /app/instance/as_b/logsarchive/log_20151128_111500/weekend.log
16186 Nov 28 11:20 /app/instance/as_c/logsarchive/log_20151128_112000/weekend.log
31297 Nov 28 11:25 /app/instance/aunz/logsarchive/log_20151128_112500/weekend.log
24533 Nov 29 10:10 /app/instance/aunz/logsarchive/log_20151129_101033/weekend.log
```

Expected output:

```
32704 Nov 28 11:10 /app/instance/as_a/logsarchive/log_20151128_111000/weekend.log
30931 Nov 28 11:15 /app/instance/as_b/logsarchive/log_20151128_111500/weekend.log
16186 Nov 28 11:20 /app/instance/as_c/logsarchive/log_20151128_112000/weekend.log
50945 Nov 28 08:30 /app/instance/naeu/logsarchive/log_20151128_083000/weekend.log
24533 Nov 29 10:10 /app/instance/aunz/logsarchive/log_20151129_101033/weekend.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for dir in /app/instance/*; do
    ls -lcrt "$dir/logsarchive"/*/weekend.log | tail -n 1
done
```

The loop goes through the subdirectories of `/app/instance` one by
one, and `tail -n 1` keeps only the last line from `ls`, which is
sorted by time. I may not have the exact same `ls` format that you
used, but this should be close to what you are looking for.

Comment: This will work nicely if the file's timestamp is the same as the directory that contains it, which may well be a valid assumption.

Comment: Good point, @AndyDalton, I guess we will have to wait for the asker to say whether that assumption is valid, and else resort to sorting outside of ls.

Comment: correct. file timestamp is the same as the dir. works perfect! thanks!